# Special function in telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=[" "])
def send_command(message):
    bot.send_message(message,"message")
```

For a bot, how could I use a special function in the code above?

```
While True:
     Time.sleep(1)
     bot.SendMessage(234235234543453, "message")
```